# Datatables Summation Row to Support Characters?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I am looking to add a summation row to my rails application that is using Datatables.

My data is being presented with a comma as is 999,999

I noticed that this code:

```
  $('#example').dataTable( {
      "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {

       var TotalMarks = 0;
      for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
   {
    TotalMarks += aaData[i][12]*1;
   }

   var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
   nCells[1].innerHTML = TotalMarks;
   }
  });
```

will only add up if I remove the (,). Is there a way to have it added with the (,) still in place?

Answer (score 2):

The content of `aaData` is of type string. So you must use some conversion :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  fnFooterCallback: function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
      var TotalMarks = 0;
      for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ ) {
        console.log(TotalMarks, aaData[i][3]);
        TotalMarks = TotalMarks + parseFloat(aaData[i][3].replace(',','.'));
       }
   }
});
```

`console-log` for demonstration purposes, see fiddle (with a lot of 999,999 and the like in column `#3`) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uqN2L/**

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used this example but it added the number of records for that column instead of taking the values inside and adding them all up for a total

Comment: Have you seen the TotalMarks adding in the console in the fiddle? You have to change aaData[i][3] to aaData[i][12]

Comment: Yes. I have updated my code to reflect [12] instead of [3]. Unfortunately, from the JS Fiddle I do not where [3] has a total value of all the entries. I just see some 999,999 entries. I checked the footer but did not see a specific summation row for that column.

Comment: My issue is when the 999,999 entries exist, the summation row give me an "NaN" value

Comment: Updated the answer and the fiddle!! To answer your comment, this is because i log `console.log(TotalMarks, aaData[i][3]);` - havent cared about displaying the value, that should be a nobrainer.

Comment: Curious..why are you calling a replacement of (,) to a (.)? I need it to display the (,). So if I was summing up column [3] and it had three rows of values each being, lets say 10,000 for example, the summation would be 30,000. Also is there a way to advise it just to place a comma for every three places? I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: It is to make parseFloat correct, it need dots. You can always set TotalMarks back to comma notation by `TotalMarks = TotalMarks.replace('.',',');` ParseFloat can parse a lot -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat but needs dot notation.

Comment: Thank you for the education on the issue. +1